# visual c++ 2008: no .dll and .lib files generated

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I am trying to create a .dll and .lib from a project so that I can link to it from a different project, but I am having trouble actually generating the dll and the lib. I tried with the very general example from msdn:

```
//header 
namespace MathFuncs
{
class MyMathFuncs
{
public:
    // Returns a + b
    static __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);

    // Returns a - b
    static __declspec(dllexport) double Subtract(double a, double b);

    // Returns a * b
    static __declspec(dllexport) double Multiply(double a, double b);

    // Returns a / b
    // Throws DivideByZeroException if b is 0
    static __declspec(dllexport) double Divide(double a, double b);
};
}
```

//body
    #include "MathFuncs.h"
    #include

```
using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

double MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}

double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
{
    return a * b;
}

double MyMathFuncs::Divide(double a, double b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        throw new invalid_argument("b cannot be zero!");
    }

    return a / b;
}
```

}

I've set the configuration type from properties to Dynamic Library (.dll). But when I build the project, the only output I get is: BuildLog.htm, MathFuncs.obj, mt.dep, MathFuncs.dll.intermediate.manifest, vc90.idb, vc90.pdb. I don't know what I am missing, can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Use the proper project template: Win32 Project.  Select DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dll was being outputted to a directory pointed by $OutDir/$ProjectName.dll the whole time..